Проблемы с фавиконами
Проблема в самопроизвольном появлении фавикона Яндекс, который я не устанавливал.
Вот скриншот вкладки:
Код такой:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: e.png;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Как видно, никаких фавиконов не указывается.
Попробовал переименовать - всё стало как было.
И ещё продолжает не отображатся фон через css.
Пробовал задать свой фавикон в имени новый 1
вот результат:
Это тот фавикон, который я сам поставил.
Это конечный код;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="e.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
        body {
            background: e.png;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body></html>

Никак не пойму в чём причина. Пробовал из другого расположения открывать - получилось как должно. Переместил обратно - пошёл старый фавикон из второго скриншота.
Осталось так даже после удаления файла e.png
Подскажите, в чём проблема, может что-то с браузером?
Использую гугл версия 125

Какой у вас браузер? Уж не яндекс ли?

@SwaD, нет, гугл 125 версии

Скорее всего фавикон остался в кэше с какого-то прежнего файла — чистить кэш

@DaniilLoban, Тогда его надо будет чистить каждый раз поле смены фавикона а это не особо удобно будет - они у меня периодически обновляются (качество улучшаю)

Не работайте с схемой file:, используйте простенький сервер и http:. В сервере установите чтобы файлы не кешировались клиентом и всё заработает.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, тут вся собака в том, что я пока его ещё не загрузил на хост и просто тестирую локально              Получается это гугл кэширует?       Если да придётся использовать Интернет Эксплорер (Другие браузеры аппаратно не поддерживаются)           (я думал из скриншотов видно что это локальный файл)

Запускайте сервер локально. Да кеширует: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64243532/get-favicon-from-chrome-cache

Сервер тоже не поддерживается железом                 Я еле как нашёл на просторах сети поддерживаемую версию гугла

Тогда буду писать скрипт для чистки папки с фавиконками

Посмотрел в папке AppData - нет никаких фавиконов.

А вы на чем таком пишите, что у вас ничего не поддерживается? И даже какой нить openserver не встанет? Или от IDE можно попробовать запустить сервер(вы же не в блокноте пишите?). nodejs поставить и побыстрому запустить сервер?

Обычно это какой-то конкретный файл имя которого постоянно и так его можно находить, но возможно в разных OC разные папки и пр, как и у браузеров что-то может отличаться, чистить кэш полностью не очень удобный вариант

@SwaD, Intel Celeron D 478 socket; 1 Gb RAM и Windows 2000 и плюс половина компонентов ломаная и могу только портативное ПО использовать т.к. установщики не запускаются вообще

В смысле вообще никаких кэшированных фавиконов не видел ни в гугле и не в эксплорере           И кажется моя глючная винда сама кэширует фавиконы как в дополнение для кэша иконок конкретно для гугла
